# Need to understand cpio -d and --make-directories

Tags: cpio

I am studying for the LPIC exam and the command `cpio` with options `-d` and `--make-directories` came up.

Would someone be able to provide an example on how these work.

```
cpio -d
cpio --make-directories
```

Answer (score 3):

Those two option do the same, they make the directory towards where the file is to be created. If you don't specify either of those options and the directory where a file is going to be created doesn't exist, then `cpio` will throw an error.

```
cd /tmp
mkdir -p test1/a 
cd test1/a
touch x1 x2
find . | cpio -pmv ../b
```

Gives an error: `cpio ../b/./x1 Cannot open: No such file or directory`
Whereas:

```
find . | cpio -pmv --make-directories ../b
```

will actually create `/tmp/test1/b` and copy the files there. You could of course have made that single directory by hand, but if you are copying a complex directory hierarchy that is not feasable.